# How to bind a object into a array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an object like that

```
var users = [new User(),new User()];
```

Where inside I have another object like that

```
var location = new Location();
```

Then on my View I would bind my users array and when I bind the Location object I wouldn't type "Location.MyProperty1", "Location.MyProperty2" foreach bind but I would type just "MyProperty1", "MyProperty2"

it's not a bug, it's just a question.
Can I do a binding like that using knockout?

Comment: how are you binding location i mean that are you using foreach binding for location?

Comment: no, I doing foreach for users

Comment: @xdumaine how you can see wasn't so hard to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the "with" binding, which creates a new binding context from an object:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: city"> </h1>
<p data-bind="with: coords">
    Latitude: <span data-bind="text: latitude"> </span>,
    Longitude: <span data-bind="text: longitude"> </span>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        city: "London",
        coords: {
            latitude:  51.5001524,
            longitude: -0.1262362
        }
    });
</script>
```

Taken from [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)